# Problem with setTimeout()

Tags: javascript

This is my code. What I want it to do is write 0, wait one sec, write 1, wait one sec, write 2, wait one sec, etc. Instead it writes 5 5 5 5 5

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    setTimeout("document.write(i + ' ')", 1000);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xb7Eb/

Comment: Do you want a `1s` wait before printing 0?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) You set all the timeouts to last 1 second at the same time. The loop doesn't wait for the timeout to occur. So you have 5 timeouts that all execute at the same time.

2) When the timeouts execute, the loop is long since complete and `i` has become 5. So once they execute, they all print "5"

3) `document.write()` writes somthing onto the page, in the same place it executes. I.e. if you have `<script>document.write("xyz")</script>` in the middle of a piece of text, it'll write "xyz" in the middle of the text. The timeouts, however, are not necessarily anywhere on the page. They exist only in code.

Here's a solution that's as close to yours as possible: http://jsfiddle.net/rvbtU/1/

```
var container = document.getElementById("counter");
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    setTimeout("container.innerHTML += '" + i + " ';", 1000 * i);
}
```

However, that solution uses setTimeout's ability to evaluate a string as javascript, which is never a good idea.

Here's a solution that uses an anymous function instead: http://jsfiddle.net/YbPVX/1/

```
var container = document.getElementById("counter");
var writer = function(number) {
    return function() { container.innerHTML += String(number) + " "; };
}
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(writer(i), 1000 * i);
}
```

Edit: Forgot to save the 2nd fiddle. Whoops. Fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

<del>Most of the answers available are giving bad advice.</del>* Specifically, you shouldn't be passing a string to `setTimeout` anymore (it still works, but it's discouraged), it's no longer `2000`, there are better ways to do this.

`setTimeout` takes a function as the first parameter, and that's what you should do, however there are some issues when calling `setTimeout` in a loop.

This looks like it should work:

```
var i;
for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
{
  setTimeout(function(){
    document.write( i + ' ' );
  }, 1000 * (i + 1) );
}
```

But it doesn't. The issue is that by the time `setTimeout` executes the function, the loop will have incremented `i` to `5`, so you'll get the same value repeated.

There are a few fixes. If you're willing to risk a `with` statement, you could try the following:

```
var i;
for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
{
  with( { i:i } )
  {
    setTimeout(function(){
      document.write( i + ' ' );
    }, 1000 * (i+1) );
  }
}
```

Note that `with` is typically discouraged just like passing `string` values to `setTimeout`, so I don't really suggest this method of doing things.

The better way is to use a closure:

```
var i;
for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
{
  (function(i){
    setTimeout(function(){
      document.write( i + ' ' );
    }, 1000 * (i+1) );
  })(i);
}
```

To explain what's going on, the anonymous function wrapper (`function(i){...code...}`) executes immediately because it's wrapped in parens and passed `i` as a value:

```
(function(i){...code...})(i);
```

This forces the `i` variable that `document.write` uses to be a different one than what's being used in the `for` loop. You could even change the parameter used in the anonymous function wrapper if the difference gets too confusing:

```
(function(a){document.write(a+' ')})(i);
```

<sub>* when I started writing this question there were a number of answers describing how to fix the string to work with `setTimeout`, although they would *technically* work, they didn't include *why* they would work (because 'document.write("' + i + ' ");' evaluates `i` at the time of calling due to string concatenation, versus evaluating `i` at runtime like the previous version did), and they most certainly didn't mention that it's the bad old way of calling `setTimeout`.</sub>

Comment: You're example still shows all five numbers at the same time. You are triggering all five timeouts 1 second after the for loop runs. In order to not trigger them at the same time, you could use `i * 1000` as your delay ==> http://jsfiddle.net/pajtai/FvDTN/ ( vs how you currently have it ==> http://jsfiddle.net/pajtai/wU3vB/ )

Comment: @Peter, whoops I had meant to do `1000 * (i+1)` in each of them and somehow forgot.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
var i = 1;
function timeout(){

    document.write(i + ' ');
    i++;
    if (i == 5) return;
    setTimeout(timeout, 1000);
}
 timeout();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nnJcG/1/

Comment: I suggest you change `function(){timeout();}` to `timeout`

Answer (score 1):

You can also work with `setInterval` and `clearInterval`:

```
var i = 0;

var f = setInterval(function() {
    if(i == 4) clearInterval(f);
    document.write(++i + ' ');
}, 1000);
```

I think this code is very readable.

Comment: while i don't disagree that the code is readable, I would move the `++i` call to the line before `document.write`. In this case the line is short and the `++i` is visible, but for more complicated code, it's really easy to lose an increment operation in the middle of something else. It's better IMHO to have one operation per line.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with clousures, you can try this:

```
var timeout = function(){
    var i = 0;
    return function(){                
        document.write(i+ ' ');
            i++;
            if(i!==5)
            setTimeout(timeout,1000);
    };
}();
setTimeout(timeout,1000);
```

Here is the example in jsBin http://jsbin.com/uloyuc/edit

Answer (score 1):

First of all, *NEVER* pass a string to setTimeout.  Use a function, it's much cleaner.

Second, you have to "close over" the loop value.  I bet this is what you want.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.write(i + ' ')
    }, i * 1000);
  }(i));
}
```

See more about you a self executing function to close over a loop value here http://www.mennovanslooten.nl/blog/post/62

---

And just cause I love it, here is the equivalent in CoffeeScript whihc has the `do` keyword to help out with just this case.

```
for i in [0..4]
  do (i) ->
    setTimeout ->
      document.write "#{ i } "
    , i * 1000
```

Comment: To try out coffescript go here ==> http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/ . Click on "Try Coffeescript" at the top, paste in Squeegy's code, and hit Run.

Answer (score 1):

You could try like this:

```
var tick_limit = 5; // Or any number you wish representing the number of ticks
var counter = 0; // Or any number you wish 
var timer_interval = 1000; // Interval for the counter
var timer;

function timerTick()
{
 if(counter < tick_limit)
 {
   // Execute code and increase current count
   document.body.innerHTML+=(counter + ' '); // Append the counter value to the body of the HTML page
   counter++;
   timer = setTimeout(timerTick,timer_interval);
 }
 else
 {
  // Reset everything
  clearTimeout(timer);
  counter = 0;
 }
}

function startCounter()
{
 clearTimeout(timer); // Stop current timer
 timer = setTimeout(timerTick,timer_interval); // Start timer with any interval you wish
}
...
// Start timer when required
startCounter();
...
```

This way, calling the startCounter a number of times will result in a single timer executing the code

Comment: Since you've started putting the settings into variables, you might as well make the interval a variable, so everything can be adjusted by editing only the top of the script. ---------- Also, this only only [shows one number](http://jsfiddle.net/pajtai/qpqRX/). I think [you want setInterval](http://jsfiddle.net/pajtai/bARAv/) and not setTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

You're triggering five timeouts at the same time.

I like [**Pindatjuh's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891039/problem-with-settimeout/6891111#6891111), but here's another fun way to do it.

This way starts the next timeout when the previous one is finished:

```
// Wrap everything in a self executing anonymous function so we don't pollute
//    the global namespace.
//
//    Note: Always use "var" statments or you will pollute the global namespace!
//    For example "for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)" will pollute the global namespace
//    unless you have "var i; for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)" or 
//    "for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)" & all of that is not in the global namespace.
//    
(function() {

    // "i" will be available within doThis()
    //     you could also pass "i" as an argument
    var i = 0,
        doThis = function() {

            // setTimeout can take an anonymous function
            // or a regular function. This is better than
            // eval-ing a string.
            setTimeout(function() {
                document.write(i + ' ');
                ++i;

                // Do the function again if necessary
                if (i < 5) doThis();
            }, 1000);
        }

    // Let's begin! 
    doThis();

})();
```

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/pajtai/FCEuc/)