# Async calls with async response in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I'm building my first project with NodeJS in these days but I'm a bit confused on a task I believe it's a simple one, I guess the problem is my lack of knowledge of these async approach but I cannot find the answer anywhere.

I've a simple loop iterating over an array and for any element, based on some rule, I'll call a function or another.
Now some operation will be faster than others so I could end up with a function on element N returning sooner than the function on element N-1.
To make it simple something like this

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
      if (i%2 === 0) {
          setTimeout(function(i) {
               console.log(i);
          }, 2000);
      }
      else { console.log(i); }
}
```

so any even number will be printed with 2 seconds lag while the odd numbers will be printed immediately.
Anyway running it I get

```
1
3
5
7
9

<<2 seconds break>>

undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

looks like the even value is "lost".
How can I pass the value making sure the function won't lose the input value?
Am I missing something?

Thanks,
Mauro

Answer (score 12):

Your `setTimeout` argument function is declared to take a single parameter, `i`. When `setTimeout` calls the function with no arguments, as it does, the parameter is thus set to `undefined`.

This would seem to be be slightly better, as it no longer shadows the outer `i` variable you were originally trying to reference...

```
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(i);
}, 2000)
```

...but if you run it, you'll find it prints `10` 5 times, because every function you create is referencing the same `i` variable, whose value will be `10` when the loop exit condition becomes `true` and it terminates.

Creating a *closure* which holds the value of `i` as it was during the loop in which each `setTimout` argument function was created will do the trick:

```
setTimeout((function(i) {
  return function() {
    console.log(i);
  }
})(i), 2000)
```

Renaming the argument to the [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) we just used might help make things clearer:

```
setTimeout((function(loopIndex) {
  return function() {
    console.log(loopIndex);
  }
})(i), 2000)
```

We're:

- Creating a function which takes a single argument and returns another function.
- *Immediately* calling the "outer" function, passing it the current value of `i` (which is not an object, so is effectively passed by value).
- The "outer" function returns the "inner" function, which is passed as the argument to `setTimeout`.

This works because:

1. Creating a function in JavaScript creates a new *scope* to hold the function's argument variables and any other variables declared within it using the `var` keyword. Think of this like an invisible object with properties corresponding to the variable names.
2. All functions hold a reference to the scope in which they were defined, as part of their *scope chain*. They still have access to this scope even if it's no longer "active" (e.g. when the function it was created for returns). The "inner" function was created in a scope which contained a `loopIndex` variable, set to the value of `i` at the time the IIFE was called. So when you try to reference a variable named `loopIndex` from inside the inner function, it first checks its own scope (and doesn't find a `loopIndex` there) *then* starts walking up its scope chain - first, it checks the scope in which it was defined, which *does* contain a `loopIndex` variable, the value of which is passed to `console.log()`.

That's all a closure is - a function which has access to the scope in which it was defined, even if the function the scope was created for has finished executing.

Answer (score 1):

Although you usually use `bind` to ensure that the value of `this` inside a callback function is what you want it to be, you can also use it to modify the arguments passed to the bound function. In your case, the code could look something like this (I changed some variable names so it was clearer what's going on):

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
  if (i % 2 === 0) {
    setTimeout(function(num) {
      console.log(num);
    }.bind(this, i), 2000);
  } else {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

In this case, the function has `.bind(this, i)` attached to it. The `this` is just for padding; the first argument to `bind` is always what you want `this` to resolve to when *inside* the bound function. After that, however, we can pass in any values that we want to be added to the arguments of the bound function--in this case, we want the current value of `i` (when the function is bound) to be passed to the function.

You can read more about `bind` at the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Answer (score 0):

```
    setTimeout(function(i) {
           console.log(i);
      }, 2000);
```

Functions called from setTimeout will not be called with any parameter.
You need to create a closure.

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891039/problem-with-settimeout) and the accepted answer.

(This is not a node.js-specific problem)