# Why does variable in setTimeout callback not have expected value?

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="image_cont">
  <img src="images/pic1.jpg" alt="pic1" />
  <img src="images/pic2.jpg" alt="pic2" />
  <img src="images/pic3.jpg" alt="pic3" />
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    slide(3, "image_cont", 5000, 600);
});

function slide(numberOfImages, containerId, timeDelay, pixels) {
    //start on first image
    var i = 0;
    var style = document.getElementById(containerId).style;
    window.setInterval(function() {
        if (i >= numberOfImages){
            i = 0;
        }
        var marginLeft = (-600 * i);
        var pixelMovement = pixels/15;


////////////////////////////////////////LOOK HERE//////////////////////////////


        for (var j = 0; j * pixelMovement < 600; j++){
            window.setTimeout(function(){
//alert('marginLeft: ' + marginLeft + ' j: ' + j + ' pixelMovement: ' + pixelMovement);
//this alert shows j is 15 when it should be 0, what's going on?


/////////////////////////////////////////END//////////////////////////////////
                style.marginLeft = (marginLeft - j * pixelMovement) + "px";
                }, 150);
        }
        i++;
    }, timeDelay);
}
```

Comment: Could add the HTML of the page?

Comment: it seems to work fine for me, but couldn't you replace `document.getElementById(containerId)` with `$('containerId')`?

Comment: There is only variable named `j` <-- understand that and understand the issue :) This is a highly duplicated question on SO and a slightly confusing aspect of closures in JavaScript. Remember, closures bind to free-variables (*not values*) and only a new function scope can introduce new variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use the variable j directly in the setTimeout function because that function runs some time later after your `for` loop has completed and thus j has the terminating value, not the value when you called setTimeout.

You can capture the current value of j in a function closure that would be available in the setTimeout function like this:

```
for (var j = 0; j * pixelMovement < 600; j++){
    window.setTimeout(function(cntr) {
        return function() {
            style.marginLeft = (marginLeft - cntr * pixelMovement) + "px";
        };
    } (j), 150);
}
```

I find this type of closure kind of confusing.  I'll try to explain what's happening.  We pass to the `setTImeout()` function the result of executing an anonymous function that takes one parameter (which I named cntr here) and we pass the value of `j` as the value of that parameter.  When that function executes (which now has the value of `j` available inside it), that function returns another anonymous function.  This other anonymous function is what `setTimeout` will actually call when it fires.  But, this second anonymous function is inside a function closure from the first function that has the captured value of `j` in it (as a variable that I renamed `cntr` while inside the function closure to avoid confusion in explaining it).  It's the anonymous functions that make it so confusing, but it works.

Comment: Thanks for the lesson, I think I mostly understand it. Unfortunately my script is still behaving in an unexpected manner. My wizardry is not strong enough.

Answer (score 1):

It should be anything, because `window.setTimeout` is an "async" function so it returns immediately after executing.

So in your code the `for` loop keeps looping and after a while (150ms) your function is being executed and the `j` variable's actual value is printed out.

Answer (score 0):

The functions you create and pass to `setTimeout` are all referencing the same loop counter variable `j` - after the loop has run its course, `j` will be set at the value which caused the loop to terminate. You need to use a closure to ensure the functions you're creating in the inner loop have access to the value `j` had at *the time the function was defined*.

See this answer for more detail on the problem and the solution:

- [Async calls with async response in NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116150/async-calls-with-async-response-in-nodejs/7116313#7116313)

(Silly variable name to make it clear that it's distinct from `j`):

```
window.setTimeout((function(jWhenFunctionWasDefined) {
  return function() {
    style.marginLeft = (marginLeft - jWhenFunctionWasDefined * pixelMovement) + "px";
  }
})(j), 150)
```