# Unexpected values when passing object to function in settimeout()

Tags: javascript, object, settimeout

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213528/why-does-variable-in-settimeout-callback-not-have-expected-value), which helped me a lot and I was able to successfully utilize 2 integers with a settimeout().  However, when passing objects it doesn't seem to work.

[Full fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/scottbeeson/vTY8U/6/)

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var me = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    }
    var child = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    }
    
    function showxydiff(obj1, obj2, when) {
        var xdiff = (obj1.x - obj2.x);
        var ydiff = (obj1.y - obj2.y);
        $('#' + when).append(xdiff + ':' + ydiff + '... ');
    };
    
    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        child.x = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
        child.y = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
        showxydiff(child, me, 'now');
        setTimeout(function (obj1, obj2) {
            return function () {
                showxydiff(obj1, obj2, 'later');
            }
        }(child,me), 500);
    }
});
```

And here are the results:

> now: 57:37... 98:50... 72:87... 66:31... 28:30...
>
> later: 28:30... 28:30... 28:30... 28:30... 28:30...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the same child object is being used for every one of your `setTimeout()` calls thus the `for` loop modifies the object that all the `setTimeout()` callbacks will use.  This means they all end up with the same value.  This is because objects are passed by reference (no copy is made) so all your callbacks have a reference to the exact same object.

You need to either create a new child object for each `setTimeout()` or pass just the `.x` and `.y` values separately.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    // create new child object for each time through the loop
    child = {};
    child.x = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
    child.y = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
    showxydiff(child, me, 'now');
    setTimeout(function (obj1, obj2) {
        return function () {
            showxydiff(obj1, obj2, 'later');
        }
    }(child,me), 500);
}
```

I also prefer this method of creating the closure (simpler for me to understand):

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    // create new child object for each time through the loop
    // use more compact javascript literal syntax
    child = {x: Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1), y: Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1)};
    showxydiff(child, me, 'now');
    // use an immediately invoking function expression
    // to create a closure to capture the current child object reference
    (function(obj1, obj2) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            showxydiff(obj1, obj2, 'later');
        }, 500);
    })(child, me);
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Qbd6V/

Comment: Why doesn't something like this fix the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/scottbeeson/vTY8U/8/ ?

Comment: @ScottBeeson - because `var a = child` does not create a copy - just a reference.  So, `a` and `child` refer to the exact same object.  Objects and Arrays are passed or assigned by reference (not by copy).

Comment: The reason I ask is because I'm doing some incremental stuff (child.x += something) and stuff based on i, so creating a new object each time becomes a pain.

Comment: I see.  And there's no way to override that behavior?  var a = child.copy?  :D

Comment: So I just added a baseX and baseY variable that I increment and I am now declaring the object in each iteration.  It is working.  I'm going to try the other solution before choosing an answer though.

Comment: @ScottBeeson - you can explicity make a copy by copying properties or by creating a new object.  It took one new line of code in my answer to create a new child object for each iteration of the loop.  The other answer is not actually doing the `setTimeout()` - it's executing immediately.

Comment: Yeah, I see that... :(

Comment: YOu have an extra ) in your second example, right?  Making sure I'm not missing something :)

Comment: @ScottBeeson - I don't think there's an extra paren.  The second block of code is copied right from the working jsFiddle.  The IIFE works like this: `(function(arg1, arg2) {code here})(passArg1, passArg2);`.   See [here](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) for details.

Comment: Yeah I was confused because in the closure example you pass the objects after, but in the other example it's still inside of the setTimeout.  Thanks

Comment: @ScottBeeson - my two examples are two different approaches to solve the same issue.  Both pass the parameters into a closure to "freeze" them for use in the `setTimeout()`.  I find the second method easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of closure. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var me = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    };
    var child = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    };

    function showxydiff(obj1, obj2, when) {
        var xdiff = (obj1.x - obj2.x);
        var ydiff = (obj1.y - obj2.y);
        $('#' + when).append(xdiff + ':' + ydiff + '... ');
    };

    function callTimeout(obj1, obj2) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            showxydiff(obj1, obj2, 'later');
        }, 500);
    }

    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        child.x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        child.y - Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        showxydiff(child, me, 'now');
        // create a new object for removing referencing
        callTimeout($.extend({}, child), $.extend({}, me));
    }
});
```

Results:

```
now:
2:59... 6:96... 34:6... 60:3... 71:54...
later:
2:59... 6:96... 34:6... 60:3... 71:54...
```

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vTY8U/11/ (using extend of jquery to create a separate object)

http://jsfiddle.net/vTY8U/10/ (create a local child object)

For more info on closure, go through docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Comment: Your `setTimeout()` isn't working.  It's executing the function immediately.  Try changing the `setTimeout()` time to 5000.  It still comes up immediately.

Comment: @jfriend00: Thnx for pointing this out, look at the edited post. There are two ways to do this. One with $.extend() and another by creating a local object.

Comment: `$.extend()` is jQuery's utility function for copying properties from one object to another.  This question doesn't mention jQuery so we generally don't use it if it's not asked for or mentioned by tag.  But it's easy to copy properties yourself.

Comment: Yes, but the JSfiddle link which is provided contains jquery 1.10.1 and he uses jquery as well in $(document).ready().

Comment: Fair enough, the OP is using jQuery.