# JavaScript setTimeout 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Trying to get a `setTimeout` to load a JS after 5 seconds, I can't seem to get it to work; closest one I can find on the forums is this [Problem with setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891039/problem-with-settimeout)

What I was trying was this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function()
    {
        var load = setTimeout(redirect, 5000);
        redirect.src = src="js/load.js";
    }
</script>
```

JavaScript is not my strongest area.

Comment: `50000` is `50 seconds`. Use `5000` instead.

Comment: What is `redirect`? Your code makes no sense in its current state.

Comment: `redirect` should be a function (or a string, but that's discouraged). It appears to be a DOM element. I'd suggest you read [the documentation](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/window.setTimeout.html) again.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming you mean to dynamically load JS resource, here's the way to do it.

First, have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="redirect"></script>
```

And the code:

```
var load = setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("redirect").src="js/load.js";
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Dude you are amazing! +1 for sure my code was so far off I can't believe you understood what I was trying to do!

Comment: Why bother having an empty script element when you can just dynamically create the element and set its `src`, adding it to the page? I'm surprised setting the `src` works with script elements actually works

Comment: @Ian just old habit I have, for some reason I don't like injecting script elements into the head or body. I prefer to know in advance what elements I got.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Interesting, I've never seen that used. Just as effective

Answer (score 1):

```
var myFunction = function(){
    // your function stuff in here.
};
setTimeout(myFunction, 5000);
```

In this case, the function is available separately from the setTimeout as well.

Answer (score -2):

You have to create a loop function that does what you want.
Like this:

```
(function myloop (i){

        setTimeout(function(){
            //HERE IS YOUR CODE DO WHAT YOU WANT
        },5000)
    })(i);
```